# AlarmManager setInexactRepeating fires before specified trigger time

Tags: java, android

I know that setInexactRepeating is not exact but it also says that it will not fire before the requested time, which seems to happen in my case. I set the alarm to fire after every 10001 milliseconds and cancel it after 10000 milliseconds using a regular runnable timer (cancelling the alarm seems to work fine) and set the alarm again to fire after every 10001 milliseconds in that runnable timer but sometimes it will fire earlier before the new requested time set in the new alarm. The alarm should not even fire at all since I use the runnable timer to cancel it and the phone is not sleeping, so the timer is running all the time.

My code:

```
//MainService.java:
public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10001, 10001, pIntent);
        MainActivity.showToast(appContext, "set alarm: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() + 10001));
    }
}

public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pIntent != null) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
            MainActivity.showToast(appContext, "cancel alarm");
        }
    }
}

public static Runnable timerInterval = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cancelAlarm(appContext);
        handler.postDelayed(timerInterval, 10000);
        setAlarm(appContext);
    }
};

//AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.showToast(context, "alarm");
        if (MainService.service) {
            MainService.handler.removeCallbacks(MainService.timerInterval);
            MainService.handler.postDelayed(MainService.timerInterval, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the intended behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution I could come up with. I think it is because there is some delay with alarmManager.cancel(pIntent), sometimes it does not cancel it on time and the alarm event will fire (even though it is supposed to be canceled), so I'm basically ignoring it when that happens, but seems a bit like a hack to do it this way. If someone knows a proper way to instantly cancel the alarm, please let us know!

```
//MainService.java:
public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10001, 10001, pIntent);
        MainActivity.showToast(appContext, "set alarm: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() + 10001));
    }
}

public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pIntent != null) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
            MainActivity.showToast(appContext, "cancel alarm");
        }
    }
}

public static long timerIntervalTime;
public static Runnable timerInterval = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timerIntervalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        cancelAlarm(appContext);
        handler.postDelayed(timerInterval, 10000);
        setAlarm(appContext);
    }
};

//AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (MainService.service) {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - MainService.timerIntervalTime) >= 10001) { //this alarm was canceled but for some reason still fired, possibly because of some delay with canceling
                MainActivity.showToast(context, "alarm");

                MainService.handler.removeCallbacks(MainService.timerInterval);
                MainService.handler.postDelayed(MainService.timerInterval, 10000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```